# Unable to play media player in Background

Tags: android

I have Implemented A media player But the Problem is that when i press back button .music stop.but it runs when the app is in background.

Comment: stop music in on pause of the acitivity

Comment: So which one is your desired behavior?

Comment: so are you unable to play in background or it runs when the app is in a background?

Comment: You have to use a media player service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper approach is to implement media-player inside service. That way music playback will persist when users uses other applications or gets outside of your app.

Remember to call `startForeground()` with ongoing notification.